# How do I add a custom .aspx page to sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've recently created an aspx and aspx.cs page that needs to run alongside a sitecore website.  Does anyone know how i can add these pages into the site?  Our set up is very odd and would like to know recommendations before trying anything and risking breaking our setup.

Comment: just add that url to IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting as |custom.aspx this will ensure this page does not get processed by sitecore item resolver

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to add your page to the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes`.
Before the `ItemResolver` is executed, the `FileResolver` is executed which checks if your request points directly to a file on disk.

You do need to configure the allowed URL extensions in the `FilterUrlExtensions` processor of the `preprocessRequest` pipeline, as such:

```
<preprocessRequest
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx</param>
      <param desc="Blocked extensions (comma separated)">*</param>
    </processor>
</preprocessRequest>
```

So that configuration will allow `*.aspx`, `*.ashx` and `*.asmx` to be requested directly (it's the default configuration in Sitecore 7.0).

If you're using Sitecore 6.6 or lower, the `FilterUrlExtensions` processor can be found in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline.

Comment: Will this work for pages I don't want to include in sitecore?  Basically the page just shows an xml output and doesnt need to be included in the actual website

Comment: Yes, you can just add the files to your web root and you should be able to browse to them. As long as you've included the file extension in the configuration as I mention in my answer.

Comment: @RuudvanFalier This only works when you put the file under web root not within a folder?

Answer (score 5):

If you just drop the ASPX page in at the path you'd like it to reside, by default, Sitecore should let it be served as is by going to the corresponding URL.

Comment: No, Sitecore will throw a 404 if the item is not found in the Content tree. You need to modify the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` in Sitecore 6

Comment: Not true, Jammykam. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the pages to the projects as normal (as DustinDavis suggested) but you also need to  modify `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` in web.config (or add a config patch file) and include the pages or folders as pipe delimited values that you want the Sitecore handlers to ignore.

> You can configure the value attribute of  the
>   /configuration/sitecore/settings/setting element in web.config with
>   name  IgnoreUrlPrefixes to prevent Sitecore from processing specific
>   requests, causing ASP.NET to  process the request without Sitecore.

From [Sitecore Presentation Component Reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/presentation_component_reference-a4.pdf)

There is more information about the how and why in [this blog post by Alex Ahyba](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/05/teach-sitecore-to-ignore-directory.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have  sitecore open in Visual Studio, just add them in to the project. You can access the new page directly.